# lodash: running function inside assign()

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm a bit stuck on this problem.

Essentially I want to update db.address if reqBody.address exists and use the existing value if it's not.
I'm currently having to traversing my db json twice; first to set a variable to the original address, and then again when assigning/merging when determining whether to use the newly created variable or reqBody.address.

I only want to traverse once.

Aside from the obvious check to only do this if reqBody.address is present I'm wondering whether this can be done in a single statement by returning the value from a function inside the assign.

Below is my code so far and I want to eliminate the entire first db_address chain command and have the second chain command use something like:

```
.merge({ address: req_address || address }  })
```

where the address following the || is the original value.

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const moment = require('moment');

let reqBody = {"address_list":[{"address_type":"Home","address":"99 West Street"}]}
let db = {"users":[{"id":1,"name":"Joe","address_list":[{"address_type":"Home","address":"11 High Street","created_date":"2018-01-08","updated_date":""}]}]}

let req_address = reqBody.address_list[0].address;
let db_address  = _.chain(db)
               .get('users').find({id: 1})
               .get('address_list')
               .filter((address) => {return address.address_type === reqBody.address_list[0].address_type})
               .get('[0].address')
               .value()

db_address = _.chain(db)
          .get('users').find({id: 1})
          .get('address_list')
          .filter((address) => {return address.address_type === reqBody.address_list[0].address_type})
          .get('[0]')
          .merge({ address: req_address || db_address },
                 { updated_date: moment().format() }
                )
          .value()

console.log(db_address)
```

Thanks in advance

Cheers

PS: Thanks again Markus for the highlighting the merge

Comment: Updated per Markus' merge suggestion to clean the code.  My Q is around how *not* to have to traverse the JSON twice, once to set the variable and once to assign/merge the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to update the value in db use `.merge({ adress: req_address })` you don't need the first chain, merge won't overwrite if the value is undefined:

> Source properties that resolve to undefined are skipped if a destination value exists.

This will still update the timestamp though, not sure if that is a problem.

Alternatively, use `update`, which is the `function funning inside assign` you asked for and will also allow not updating the timestamp.

Version with `merge`

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const moment = require('moment');

let reqBody = {"address_list":[{"address_type":"Home","address":"99 West Street"}]}
let db = {"users":[{"id":1,"name":"Joe","address_list":[{"address_type":"Home","address":"11 High Street","created_date":"2018-01-08","updated_date":""}]}]}

let req_address = reqBody.address_list[0].address;

db_address = _.chain(db)
          .get('users').find({id: 1})
          .get('address_list')
          .filter((address) => {return address.address_type === reqBody.address_list[0].address_type})
          .get('0')
          .merge({ address: req_address },
                 { updated_date: moment().format() }
                )
          .value()

console.log(db_address)
```

Version with update

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const moment = require('moment');

let reqBody = {"address_list":[{"address_type":"Home","address":"99 West Street"}]}
let db = {"users":[{"id":1,"name":"Joe","address_list":[{"address_type":"Home","address":"11 High Street","created_date":"2018-01-08","updated_date":""}]}]}

let req_address = reqBody.address_list[0].address;

db_address = _.chain(db)
          .get('users').find({id: 1})
          .get('address_list')
          .filter((address) => {return address.address_type === reqBody.address_list[0].address_type})
          .update(
            '0',
            address =>
              req_address ?
                {
                  ...address,
                  address: req_address,
                  updated_date: moment().format()
                } :
                address
          )
          .value()

console.log(db_address)
```

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for the response.  It certainly makes the code more readable and I'll be incorporating it :-)
I'll tweak my Q but I'm actually trying to figure out how *not* to have to create the db_address value in the first place so that I don't have to traverse twice (once to set the variable and again to assign).  Hence the merge would look more like this: `{ address: req_address || address }`  where the `address` is the value in the db JSON

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a little more I simply added `this` and it's now working ... awesome.

```
          .merge({ address: req_address || this.address },
                 { updated_date: moment().format() }
                )
```

Cheers

Comment: Nice.
Also check out my updated answer, might be simpler.
I'm still struggling with the embedded editor though...

Comment: Thanks @Markus for the `update` example.  It actually answered another question I had which was "how do I run a function within the chain".
I added a key:value in the db-JSON `"address_changed": 2`  and then used the update to run an inline function: `.update('address_changed', value => { return value + 1 } )`  which works very well.  
Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: That's a good example for it's use case, update a value dependent on it's current value.
For full functional shenanigans, you could use a curried `add` from `lodash/fp` bound to `1`, but I'll leave that to your own judgement.